# meaning of normalized mutual information

Tags: correlation, mutual-information

I read a paper which shows the value of normalized mutual information for two random variables is around 0.1 to 0.2 and it says so these two variables are statistical significantly correlated. I don't know why? How big the normalized mutual information is so that the variables are correlated?

Comment: "Statistical significance" is not a concept that applies to random variables: it applies to *hypothesis tests* concerning *data*.  What data are involved here?  Exactly what paper are you reading?

Comment: @whuber thanks! you are right, I think it's hypothesis test to check if two series of samples are correlated or not. The paper is http://www.maxlittle.net/publications/prd_updrs2hy.pdf and the mutual information results are shown at table 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good comparison point. The mutual information between two variables distributed according to a bivariate normal is

$$-\frac{1}{2} \log (1-\rho^2)$$

So if your mutual information is $I$, you can think of

$$1-e^{-2I}$$

as a generalised $R^2$

Comment: Presumably those two variables have identical (Normal) distributions, right?

Comment: The formula gives the mutual informaiton as a function of correlate for any bivariate normal distribution, regardless of the covariance matrix.

Of course, in your case, the data may have a different joint distribution, but this should give you at least a point of comparison.

Comment: Another useful comparison would be a bivariate Bernoulli.

Comment: is there a source article from where $1-e^{-2I}$ comes from discussing its usage?